# How to define a DaemonSet to create slightly different pods?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

How can I define a single definition of DaemonSet to create slightly different pods from it?
What I mean by different pods is that pods created from different commands.
I currently make two different DaemonSet objects to create two different kinds of pods.

Let me tell you the details.

I've been modifying kube-flannel.yml, especially the definition of DaemonSet.
I want to add "--iface=" to flanneld [ "/opt/bin/flanneld", "--ip-masq", "--kube-subnet-mgr"]
and I want to use two different ethernet interfaces based on node label.

I have three different kinds of nodes:
1) a master node with two ethernet interfaces: eth0 for internal network and eth3 for external network 
2) slave nodes with one ethernet interfaces: eth0 for internal network
3) a newly added node with one ethernet interfaces: p2p1 for internal network

When I had 1) and 2), I was okay with the following command:
[ "/opt/bin/flanneld", "--ip-masq", "--kube-subnet-mgr", "--iface=--eth0"] 
I have to add --iface option because otherwise flanneld on the master node automatically detects eth3 other than eth0, 
which is the reason I manually add the iface option.

Now that I have 3),
I have to make two DaemonSet definitions with different commands:
[ "/opt/bin/flanneld", "--ip-masq", "--kube-subnet-mgr", "--iface=--eth0"]  for 1) and 2)
, [ "/opt/bin/flanneld", "--ip-masq", "--kube-subnet-mgr", "--iface=--p2p1"] for 3) 
Label selector is used to tell which DaemonSet is used for a node. 
The entire definition is attached at the end.

Is there a more elegant way of creating slightly different pods from a single DaemonSet definition?
It would be nice to have only a single definition with a placeholder which can be substituted by the value of a specific label.

Otherwise I can do this by setting flannel in a different way?
It would be nice if we can give a list of ethernet interfaces to --iface option but my colleague found that only one interface/ip can be given to --iface option.

Thanks.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: flannel
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-cfg
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
data:
  cni-conf.json: |
    {
      "name": "cbr0",
      "type": "flannel",
      "delegate": {
        "isDefaultGateway": true
      }
    }
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
    }
--- 
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
    iface: eth0
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
        iface: eth0
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
        iface: eth0
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.7.0-amd64
        command: [ "/opt/bin/flanneld", "--ip-masq", "--kube-subnet-mgr", "--iface=eth0" ]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.7.0-amd64
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "set -e -x; cp -f /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conf; while true; do sleep 3600; done" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-gpu-flannel-ds
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
    iface: p2p1
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
        iface: p2p1
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
        iface: p2p1
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.7.0-amd64
        command: [ "/opt/bin/flanneld", "--ip-masq", "--kube-subnet-mgr", "--iface=p2p1" ]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.7.0-amd64
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "set -e -x; cp -f /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conf; while true; do sleep 3600; done" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
```

Comment: To see the discussion on Google Groups, visit the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/F6GvfHoX7V4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more advanced logic regarding container commands, I can suggest 2 options.

1. Build a custom docker image based on `quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.7.0-amd64` and add a script that does the logic (e.g. based on the output of `ifconfig | grep p2p1`). Use the script as the container command (either specify this in the Dockerfile or in the POD spec).
2. The same script can also be but into a ConfigMap and mounted into the container, the same way you already did it with the flannel config. You can then change the `command` of the container to execute this script. Example command: `["/bin/sh", "/etc/kube-flannel/entrypoint.sh"]`

Option 2 seems to be easier and more flexible in my opinion.